# array count error swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have searched long, but couldn't find a solution for my bug. Swift somehow doesn't count my array (converted from json) correctly. This is the code I use to create the array:

```
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
let jsonDic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
var count = jsonDic.count
```

When the count should be 3, the count is 2. So I just always added 1, but now if the count should be 4, the count is still 2.

Has anyone experienced something like that or is it just me doing something wrong?

EDIT: This is an example input:

```
{"items":[{"var1":"xxx","var2":"xxx","var3":"xxx","var4":"xxx","var5":0},{"var1":"xxx","var2":"xxx","var3":"xxx","var4":"xxx","var5":0}, {"var1":"xxx","var2":"xxx","var3":"xxx","var4":"xxx","var5":0}]}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of input that causes this problem?

Comment: You are referring to an array, but I see a dictionary - mistype, or the array is an element of the dictionary and you are counting the wrong object?

Comment: Yes it' a dictionary. No I'm counting the jsonDic (which is a dictionary) @Antonio

Comment: Confused... which one should have 3 elements? the dictionary or the array contained in it?

Comment: Ah I got it! Thanks! You were right, I was counting the dictionary, but I actually wanted to count the array in the dictionary. I am counting the array using: 'jsonDic["items"]!.count' @Antonio

Comment: Ok, so I thought the right thing :) be sure to read the node in my answer about how you are accessing to that counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample data you posted is a dictionary with one `items` key, and the corresponding value is an array (so the dictionary count should be 1).

By using this code:

```
let array = jsonDic["items"] as? NSArray
array?.count
```

I see that that array has 3 elements.

If what you are trying to count  is the array, then I would use the above code, or this one using optional binding:

```
if let array = jsonDic["items"] as? NSArray {
    array.count
}
```

**NOTE**: I'd warn you about using `jsonDic["items"]!.count` because it is not safe: if the `items` key is not in the dictionary, or if its value cannot be cast to an array, then a run time exception will be thrown.